# Как отвязать привязанный мэш оружия от сокета на руке игрока

Tags: unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine-5, blueprint

Через лайнтрейс получаю информацию о том, какой объект можно поднять и вывожу виджет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом игрок может нажав "E" поднять объект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда игрок поднимает новое оружие, старое исчезало/падало на землю?
Пробовал Deatach но не получилось. Может неправильно использовал